# C# How to work-around identical keys in a Dictionary

Tags: c#

This program add's values with their other values into a dictionary, all is fine until there are identical keys (var eat(.8) and var extra(.8) with different values.  How do i ensure that i can use the right key every time even though they are similar? For example, var example = gigantDictionary[.8] (but i want var edmg value instead of '500' in the code?

```
var wqat = 1.1;  //| index 0
var rat = .2;    //| index 1
var eat = .8;    //| index 2
var baat = 1.2;  //| index 3
var extra = .8;  //| index 4


var wqdmg = 120; //| index 0
var rdmg = 60;   //| index 1
var edmg = 50;   //| index 2
var badmg = 40;  //| index 3
var extradmg = 500; //| index 4



List<double> theOneList = new List<double>();
List<double> damageList = new List<double>();

theOneList.Add(wqat);
theOneList.Add(rat);
theOneList.Add(eat);
theOneList.Add(baat);


damageList.Add(wqdmg);
damageList.Add(edmg);
damageList.Add(rdmg);
damageList.Add(badmg);

Dictionary<double, double> gigantDictionary = new Dictionary<double, double>();



for (int i = 0; i < theOneList.Count; i++)
{
    gigantDictionary.Add(theOneList[i], damageList[i]);
    gigantDictionary.Add(extra, 500); //this is the malignant similar key


}

 theOneList.Sort((c, p) => -c.CompareTo(p)); //orders the list

List<double> finalList = new List<double>(); 

 for (int i = 0; i < theOneList.Count; i++)
        {
            finalList.Add(gigantDictionary[theOneList[i]]); //grabs damage values and add's it to 'finalList'

           Console.WriteLine(finalList[i]);
        }
```

So ultimately, i want to order 'theOneList' by descent, in doing so i can get the damages from 'gigantDictionary' and put those into 'finalList', now i have an ordered damage list that i need, but since 2 keys are similar... this is holding me back.

*Edit: Could identical indexes be the key to this? be the bridge? for example, in index 0 i get 1.1 and 120, maybe the answer lies with the identical indexes, i want to get '120' damage from '1.1', notice both have index 0, this might work

Comment: dictionary is not suitable here, if keys can be duplicate

Comment: If a key can map to more than one value then you need some type of collection to map to like a list.  So maybe you actually need `Dictionary<double, List<double>>`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad what should i do?

Comment: @juharr can you explain?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are using your dictionary for, so I can only give you a suggestion to consider.  Can you expand on what you want to do with the dictionary once you create it?

Comment: @juharr edited, now you can see what im trying to do

Comment: @Adan No, the edit in no way clarifies how you want to handle duplicates.

Comment: Lets make it simple, 2 people park blue cars at vallet parking, first person comes back and wants his blue car back, while the vallet person has changed, there are only 2 blue cars in the lot, how does he know which car to bring??

Comment: At this point I don't really understand why you want to add `extra`.  In fact why not create a class that combines the key and value  then sort on the key and select the value for your final list?

Comment: *Edit: Could identical indexes be the key to this? be the bridge? for example, in index 0 i get 1.1 and 120, maybe the answer lies with the identical indexes, i want to get '120' damage from '1.1', notice both have index 0, this might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have two *separate* list for values that must go together. A better approach is to create a structure with the two values and keep a single list.

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double TheOne { get; set; }
    public double Dmg { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Thing> list=new List<Thing>() {
            new Thing() { Name = "wq", TheOne = 1.1, Dmg=120 },
            new Thing() { Name = "r", TheOne = 0.2, Dmg=60 },
            new Thing() { Name = "e", TheOne = 0.8, Dmg=50 },
            new Thing() { Name = "ba", TheOne = 1.2, Dmg=40 },
            new Thing() { Name = "extra", TheOne = 0.8, Dmg=500 },
        };

        list.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.TheOne.CompareTo(t2.TheOne));

        double[] dmg_list=list.Select((t) => t.Dmg).ToArray();

    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

A constructor to `Thing` can be used to assign values with one operation.

```
public class Thing
{
    // Constructor sets all the values
    public Thing(string name, double theone, double dmg)
    {
        this.Name=name;
        this.TheOne=theone;
        this.Dmg=dmg;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public double TheOne { get; private set; }
    public double Dmg { get; private set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Thing> list=new List<Thing>();
        list.Add(new Thing("wq", 1.1, 120));
        list.Add(new Thing("r", 0.2, 60));
        list.Add(new Thing("e", 0.8, 50));
        list.Add(new Thing("ba", 1.2, 40));
        list.Add(new Thing("extra", 0.8, 500));


        list.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.TheOne.CompareTo(t2.TheOne));

        double[] dmg_list=list.Select((t) => t.Dmg).ToArray();

    }
}
```

Comment: how do i add items in 'Name' 'TheOne' 'Dmg' dynamically? i wont be adding things manually, would it be like Name.Add('something') ?

Comment: You might want to add a constructor to `Thing`. Do you know what a constructor is?

Comment: i think i know what a constructor is.  But for example: list 'bigList' contains a varied amount of objects, how do i re-work your code so that it uses 'Thing' x amount of times instead of the manual adding above? by the way i really love the code you have there it's great, just would like it to consider dynamic amount of items, grabbed from list 'bigList'

Comment: Like `var list = bigList.Skip(10).Take(100).ToList()` or `var list = bigList.Where((t)=>t.TheOne>1.0).ToList()`

Comment: thank you, i wanted to use a 'for' loop to add items-example: list.Add(new Thing(bigList[i], fooList[i], dmgList[i])); and , thanks!

Comment: This answer is what Object oriented programming is about. Moving from multiple lists of values, or a single list of multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

They keys aren't "similar" they're "identical".  If the keys were just "similar" then, as far as the dictionary is concerned, it's no different than being "completely different".  From the point of view of a dictionary items are either equal, or not equal.

> For example,
>
> ```
> var example = gigantDictionary[.8]
> ```
>
> (but i want var edmg value instead of '500' in the code?)

But how should the dictionary possibly know that?  How would it know if you actually wanted to get 500?

Do you want to prevent the duplicate keys from being added, and instead always use the first value paired with every key?  If so, just check if a key exists before adding a new one.

Do you want to just get *all* values associated with a key, if there are duplicates?  Then have a dictionary where the value is a collection, and add all values associated with that one key to the collection.

Is there actually some way to distinguish the keys so that they're not actually identical?  Then do that.  With just a double (which is a very bad type to use as a key for a dictionary in the first place, as it's easy for floating point rounding errors to result in similar but different doubles that you consider equivalent) there's no good way to do this, but if your actual key could be different in such a way that distinguishes the two keys, then each could point to a unique value.

Comment: well, first of all, the indexing is unique to each object in the list, there are NO identical indexes in identical key's, my idea is to add a list with the indexes and use those with a dictionary to pull the damage values